# How do I get global visibility of variables

Tags: c#

I have a class which contains an another class object which in turn
create event handlers.

I need to run some code in the parent class if the event handlers are triggered. How could I solve my problem?

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new windowsform1());
    }
}

public partial class windowsform1 : Form
{
    private filewatcher watcher;

    private void button_klick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         watcher = new filewatcher(textbox.Text);
    }
}

public class filewatcher
{
    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public filewatcher(string pfad)
    {
        //... some more code
            watcher.Created += OnChanged;

            // Begin watching.
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
    }

    //event file changed
    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do some stuff with the windowsform1-object in the main thread
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you marked as correct is a lazy fix and a bad design, you will notice in the long run, the correct way of doing this:

1 - Have an event handler on children class.

```
    class ChildClass {
    EventHandler MyEventHandler { get; set; }
    ...
```

2 - Suscribe in parent´s constructor the function to be executed to the event handler of the child.

```
    childClass.MyEventHandler += MyParentFunction;
```

3 - Invoke the event handler from child, it will run the function that you suscribed in the parent´s constructor.

```
    class ChildClass {
    EventHandler MyEventHandler { get; set; }
    ...

    MyEventHandler?.Invoke();
```

Source https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.eventhandler?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Okay I get the point. But how do I exactly integrate the Changed event?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event handler in `windowsform1` for your event fired in `filewatcher`